# Fields with no spacetime?

Tags: spacetime, field-theory

Can we define field theory with reference to no spacetime in particular? If so, how could we explain the spacetime we live in and the whole spacetimes we observe in our Universe (Kerr-like, locally minkovskian, etc).

Comment: It's possible to define field theory in 0+0D by the obvious generalization.

Comment: you can have spacetime as an emergent property of the interactions of these no-spacetime located fields